# How can I create a Get request to get the sum of an object called account_manager?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have this Get route:

```
router.get('/test_cancellation', auth, async(req, res) => {
  try{
    const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.find({},{
      account_manager:1,
      fronter:1,
      closer:1, 
      management_fee:1, 
      cancellation_date:1
    }).sort({cancelltion_date:-1}); 

    res.json(model_CancellationKPI);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

And, this is the JSON that I received:

[image]

How can I create a route that take into account_manager as a parameter and use management_fee to sum the total of each account_manager? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/test_cancellation', auth, async(req, res) => {
  try{
    const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.find({},{
      account_manager:1,
      fronter:1,
      closer:1, 
      management_fee:1, 
      cancellation_date:1
    }).reduce((sum, cur)=>{
      if(sum[cur['account_manager']]){
        sum[cur['account_manager']]+=cur['management_fee'];
      }
      else{
        sum[cur['account_manager']]=cur['management_fee'];
      }
    },{}); 

    res.json(model_CancellationKPI);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: I received this error message: CancellationKPI.find(...).reduce is not a function

Comment: Does adding .toArray() before .reduce help?

Comment: @ManfredTijerino if that solved your problem, please choose my answer :)